# QAbstractTableModel SQLRelation

Tags: c++, sql, qt, api, qabstractitemmodel

I found Qt's QSQLRelation and all related QSQLxxx very useful. I'm trying to connect to a remote API through http Json API and I'm trying to design something very similar to QSQLxxx but I need some clue. Because things like QSQLRelation, there is nothing I can inherit from. So any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that may sound weird, but Assistant says you *may* subclass QSqlDriver:

> If you want to create your own SQL drivers, you can subclass this class and reimplement its pure virtual functions and those virtual functions that you need. See How to Write Your Own Database Driver for more information.

AFAIK, the main difference is that JSON isn't all that relational, compared to databases, thought you can still implement your vision of it.